# How to swiftly create a PDF document with 100 figures?

Tags: pdftex

I have PdfLaTeX installed on a machine. I have a directory "figs" that contains about 100 figures (JPG file format). I would be keen to see a single PDF for better reading of it. Ideally too an epub, but PDF would be already a great help for reading.

scaled on the width of 100% (= 1.0\pagewidth).

Would you know a quick and dirty method eventually?

Looking forward to hearing someone and help !

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your user name I guess that you're using Ubuntu Linux. Install `imagemagick` if it's not already installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then use:

```
convert *.jpg document.pdf
```

In a terminal with working directory your folder containing the images.

A quick google would have helped you a lot.

Or do you insist on using (La)TeX?